# Prevent ExtJS grid sorting

Tags: javascript, extjs5

I have grid and want to apply default sorting on it, I am getting parameters from an API. My flow is as below.

Store.sort(sorters),  where this code do load operation and after refreshing grid, It fires an event  sortchange event on first load. How can i prevent it?

Update: I tried sortOnLoad:false. But, it is not working.

Comment: I would not specify a sort definition on your store.  Then have an onload handler on your store that calls your Store.sort().  Mind posting your store definition?

Comment: `store: {
autoLoad: false,
remoteSort: true,
enablePaging: true,
sortParam: 'xyxz',
filterParam: '',
autoStores: ''
}`
My problem is whenever I want to apply sorting of remote store. but, whenever I apply It should not fireevent sortchange after refresh

Comment: So you want to perform an initial sort, but not trigger a certain listener you attached to the sortchange event? Why don't you wait to attach the listener until the initial sort is done?

Comment: Yes and I am attaching listener on view sortchange. so, It fires automatically.
if you have any other idea, Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in sortchange event there is one parameter called **column**

so,when it will called just check **column.hasFocus**. if it will true that means user sort from grid header.
and if it return false that means it's called by loading or removing data.

Hope, this information will help you..:)